# Android Studio остановка приложения

Tags: java, android

**Почему андроид студия останавливает приложение при нажатии кнопки create? В коде никаких ошибок не подсвечено и оно нормально компилируется вроде**

```
public class SmActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

LinearLayout llmain;
RadioGroup rjGroup;
Button clear, create;
TextView txt;

int wrapCont = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sm);

    llmain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llMain);
    rjGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioG);

    create = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
    create.setOnClickListener(this);

    clear =(Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
    clear.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.create:
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams IPar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wrapCont, wrapCont);
            int btnGrav = Gravity.LEFT;

            switch (rjGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
                case R.id.lleft:
                    btnGrav = Gravity.LEFT;
                    break;
                case R.id.center:
                    btnGrav = Gravity.CENTER;
                    break;
                case R.id.lright:
                    btnGrav = Gravity.RIGHT;
                    break;
            }
            IPar.gravity = btnGrav;
            Button newBtn = new Button(this);
            newBtn.setText(txt.getText().toString());

            llmain.addView(newBtn, IPar );
            break;
        case R.id.clear:
            llmain.removeAllViews();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Удалено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: добавьте в вопрос стектрейс при остановке приложения (кнопка "править" под вопросом), по вашему описанию проблемы можно уверенно сказать только одно - что то не работает, но об этом вы и сами догадались

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас не инициализирован `txt`, когда вы вызываете `newBtn.setText(txt.getText().toString());`. Соответственно, приложение падает с NPE.

Определите `txt` до вызова `onClick` (например в `onCreate`).

P.s. здесь ошибка очевидна, но на будущее - прикладывайте к вопросу стектрейс.

Comment: Хорошо, испралюсь)